# A target array with shape (687, 809) was passed for an output of shape (None, 25) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I was using CNN and got this error.

```
r = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50)
```

This was the code

and the following is the error, plz help me to solve it.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-0b7c2e7fa2ce> in <module>()
----> 1 r = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in check_loss_and_target_compatibility(targets, loss_fns, output_shapes)
    808           raise ValueError('A target array with shape ' + str(y.shape) +
    809                            ' was passed for an output of shape ' + str(shape) +
--> 810                            ' while using as loss `' + loss_name + '`. '
    811                            'This loss expects targets to have the same shape '
    812                            'as the output.')

ValueError: A target array with shape (687, 809) was passed for an output of shape (None, 25) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for these type of issues is when the data dimensions don't match the model output dimensions.

To resolve this, have a check whether you're creating the data correctly and it matches the model's last (final/output) layer dimensions.